# How does WordPress determine which template to show?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, theme

So I recently set up a Wordpress blog and I've noticed that when I make posts, the link is `http://www.domain.com/?p=2`. I was wondering how you could specify which file to use to parse such requests.

For example, domain.com/?author=1 now returns a page with all posts made by that author, but how and where does it get configured to go here? I checked to see if it was .htaccess related but it appears not to be.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress has a complex [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) that determines which template files are shown based on each page request.

Template files are called from the active theme's directory at `/wp-content/themes/theme-name`. For example, if you request a single post, the `single.php` file in the active theme's directory will be displayed. If you request an author, the `author.php` template will be displayed.

If WordPress can't find those templates, it looks for the next related template available, eventually falling back on `index.php` if it can't find specific templates, as detailed in the [hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and shown in this diagram (click for large version):[image: wordpress template hierarchy]

If you are trying to customise the author or post templates, it is best to do that by editing the `author.php` and `single.php` templates in your theme directory, rather than attempting to restructure the hierarchy (defined in `wp-includes/theme.php`) yourself.

If you are trying to create 'pretty urls', you can do that using the [Permalinks panel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) under the Settings header in the WordPress admin area.

Answer (score 0):

everything going to / will cause apache to load up `index.php`
so if you delete or rename `index.php` in the root, nothing will work

The question mark denotes the start of a query string, this will be passed to that file (`index.php`)
And from there wordpress will do its magic

`.htaccess` will turn those 'ugly' urls into pretty ones such as `/page/2` or `/authors/1`